# .htaccess changes are not reflecting in my XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a weird situation. I have a PHP application running on XAMPP. My .htaccess was configured in such a way that it was appending www to my URL. Now, I did not want that, so I tried to play around with my .htaccess (after reading things online).

Now, for some reason, whatever changes I am making in my .htaccess are not even reflecting. It got messed up, and it stays messed up!

Here is what my messed up .htaccess looks like -

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

IndexIgnore *

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

# Protect the .htaccess file itself
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Here, even if I turn off my Rewrite engine, or comment out some conditions, it still is not reflecting on my local server.

What am I missing? Am I editing the wrong .htaccess. It was by default in my htdocs folder of XAMPP. I tried restarting the server, but no use.

This is how all my URLs are now -
[image]
It is appending a . in front of all URLs

Comment: did you check if allowoverride is on? if that's off, then htaccess files are ignored.

Comment: In that case, how did it get messed up in the first place?

Comment: Where do I find allowoverride? I can turn it off, so url will be what I want it to be without over write by htaccess.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: I already googled it and tried. Its not working. I tried setting it to None, and restarted my server... same result! Why is that happening? Any possible suspects?